# Password config error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a password configuration program:

```
string password;
string password_config;

cout << "Enter password: ";
cin >> password;
cout << "Confirm password: ";
cin >> password_config;

if (password_config == "Password100")
{
    cout << "Passwords match!" << endl;
}
```

But when I type in two different passwords (for example, "fish"), the program just ends. Please help!

Comment: What did you expect it to do instead? I do not see any code to be executed when you type in two different passwords.

Comment: This isn't really enough of a program to see what it is supposed to do, and what it actually does. Please create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: BTW when you're posting a program, _post a program_. C++ doesn't allow statements hanging out in free space like you've shown here: presumably those lines of code are in a _function_. Read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s, as you were prompted in the FAQ that you studied after registering here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `if` statement wants password_config to be equal to "Password100". If `password` and `password_config` are not equal to "Password100" then the compiler pretty much ignores the `if` statement and exits.

Your `if` statement should look like this:

```
if (password == password_config) {
cout << "Passwords match!" << endl;
}
```

Now, the `if` statement will be followed through as long as `password` is equal to password_config.

Hope this helps mate!

Comment: The `if` statement isn't ignored, the condition `(stringA == stringB)` just send back a `false` statement because, well... it is false.  Therefore, the programs ignore only the following instructions inside the bracets `{ }` and prints nothing.

Comment: Ah, this is such a stupid mistake, I should have seen this. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @AntoineGuillen well it's pretty much ignored, but I get where you're coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code fragment will help you

```
string password;
string password_config;
int a=0;
do
 {
  cout << "Enter password: ";
  cin >> password;
  cout << "Confirm password: ";
  cin >> password_config;

  if (password == password_config)
   {
    cout << "Passwords match!" << endl;
    a=1;
   }
  if(a==0)
   {
    cout << "\nPasswords do not match. Enter them again\n";
   }
 }while(a!=1);
```

Your current code just checks if `password_config` is same as `"Password100"`, and if they are, it outputs `"Passwords match!"`, otherwise just exits.

Now, if you see my code, it has a variable `a` which is initialized as 0 at the start. Now in the if statement, it checks if `password` is same as `password_config`, and if they are then `"Passwords match!"` is outputted and `a`'s value becomes 1, and then, the do-while loop is exited. If they are not equal ( that is `a` is still 0, then the do-while loop will continue and ask you to enter the passwords again.

Hope this code helps you and the explanation is enough. If you need more explanation, then just ask...    :)